# Filter / subset all factors in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

Let's start with an example, for instance, the `iris` dataset (`data(iris)`).

The column `Species` is composed by three factors: `setosa`, `versicolor` and `virginica`.

I would like to subset or filter all these factors by creating, for instance, three dataframes, each corresponding to one factor. Later on, I would like to work with all of them iteratively.

I have been checking different options, but all of them focused on filtering one or two factors, not taking all of them into consideration to operate over them separately and iteratively later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frames`

```
lst1 <- split(iris, iris$Species)
```

and if we need it to bee different objects (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```